# Reading a scalar from one file then writing the string to another file?

Tags: perl

I've got a file named 'input.file' with the following line:

> Foo is $COLOR

$COLOR is assigned 'red' and I'm trying to create a second file named 'output.file' with the following line:

> Foo is red

Here's my failed attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $COLOR = "red";

open(FILE_IN, "< input.file");
open(FILE_OUT, "> output.file");

while (<FILE_IN>){

    # Prints 'Foo is $COLOR' to 'output.file'
    print FILE_OUT;
}

close FILE_IN;
close FILE_OUT;

# Prints 'Foo is red' to STDOUT
print "Foo is $COLOR\n";
```

So how do I print 'red' rather than '$COLOR' when when printing to 'output.file'?

Thanks

Comment: Replace the placeholder like `s/\$COLOR/$COLOR/g` — think of the security implications when just echoing a line would substitute variables and run arbitrary code. Good thing this isn't the case.

Comment: If your tasks gets any more complex than your example above, you should consider using a template engine like [Template Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Template%3A%3AToolkit&mode=dist), [Text::Template](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Text%3A%3ATemplate&mode=dist) or [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=HTML%3A%3ATemplate&mode=dist).

Answer (score 4):

#### A general solution

Lets assume a string contains placeholders that match the regex `/\$\w+/`. We also have a hash mapping names to values, e.g.:

```
my %replacements = (
  COLOUR => 'red',
  x => 42,
  perl_snippet => '$x++ == 3',
);
```

So the input

```
my $input = <<'END';
My favourite colour is $COLOUR.
The meaning of life is $x. Here is some Perl: `$perl_snippet`
$undefined
END
```

should transform to

```
My favourite colour is red.
The meaning of life is 42. Here is some Perl: `$x++ == 3`
$undefined
```

and *not*

```
My favourite colour is red.
The meaning of life is 42. Here is some Perl: `42++ == 3`
```

This can be achieved by matching for placeholders, using the name as a hash key, and only substituting if an appropriate entry exists in the replacement hash:

```
(my $output = $input) =~
   s/\$(\w+)/exists $replacements{$1} ? $replacements{$1} : '$'.$1/eg;
```

or

```
(my $output = $input) =~
   s/\$(\w+)(?(?{exists $replacements{$1}})|(*F))/$replacements{$1}/g;
```

This strategy of using a single substitution with a hash also guarantees that each part of the string is only evaluated once, and no double interpolation occurs.

#### A specific solution

If only one placeholder has to be interpolated, we can simplify by not using a hash:

```
s/\$COLOR/red/g;
```

This has the following disadvantages:

- You can only have one such replacement. Adding another `s///` makes double escaping possible, which is usually a bug.
- You cannot easily query or modify the substitution values or placeholders at runtime.